# Why are there multiple possible Projection Matrix definitions used in OpenGL?

Tags: math, opengl, glsl

I just read [an article on www.songho.ca](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) which indicates that a projection matrix is defined by:

```
[2n/(r-l) 0        (r+l)/(r-l)  0            ]
[0        2n/(t-b) (t+b)/(t-b)  0            ]
[0        0        -(f+n)/(f-n) -2*n*f/(f-n) ]
[0        0        -1           0            ]
```

where:

```
n: near
f: far
l: left
r: right
t: top
b: bottom
```

I have also read on [www.geeks3d.com](http://www.geeks3d.com/20090729/howto-perspective-projection-matrix-in-opengl/) of an alternate definition given by:

```
[w 0 0  0]
[0 h 0  0]
[0 0 q -1]
[0 0 qn 0]
```

where:

```
w=(2*near)/(width * aspect)
h = 2near/height
q=-(far+near)/(far-near)
qn=-2*(far*near) / (far-near)
```

Why are there differences in `M[0][2]` and `M[1][2]` (excluding one is the transposed of other)? Do they generate the same result? Which one is posible to use in GLSL without any transpose?

Comment: If you look further down the songho page, they make some assumptions and do some simplifications that make their matrix look much more like the geeks3d matrix. One looks like the transpose of the other, but if you look at the simplified songho they might turn out to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first matrix allows you to arbitrarily position the left, right, top and bottom clip plane positions. The second one always gives you a centred, symmetric frustum, which is kind of limiting. For example when you're doing stereoscopic rendering you want to slightly shift the left and right plane.

> BTW, which one is posible to use in GLSL without any transpose?

This has nothing to do with GLSL. You can use either. The transpose you're referring to stems from the way matrices are represented internally in OpenGL and interfaces to the outside world.

Anyway, you should not hardcode matrices into shader source code, but supply them through a *Uniform*.

#### Update

OpenGL orders its matrices column major, i.e.

```
0 4 8 c
1 5 9 d
2 6 a e
3 7 b f
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but please correct me this problem: is opengl matrices use row-major layout? I confused because of this http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/data.html ("All matrices in the library are row-major. That means that the matrices are stored row by row in memory, which is similar to the OpenGL matrix layout. A typical 4x4 matrix including a translational part looks like this") but i remember somewhere tell opengl use colum-major layout for matrices :(

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: OpenGL orders it's matrices column major, which has several advantages. Most importantly it gives you direct access to the transformation base vectors (which are the columns).